# How to create a for loop to open, mutate and save .csv files using R?

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, save

I have a several .csv files that have to be reformatted and saved again using an R script.
The function that is needed to do the changes and the reformating of the files, is already established and works perfectly fine. But as there are always lots of documents to change, I would like to have a for lLoop so that I don't have to adapt my code for every single document. But unfortunately I don't have experience in the use of loops using R so far.

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
setwd("C:/users/Desktop/Raw/.")
df <- read.csv("A1.csv", sep= ",")
new_df <- wrap_frame(df, nr = 61, rownames = "", unique_names = FALSE)
write.csv(new_df, "C:/users/Desktop/Data/A1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

The original .csv files are always called the same way with a letter (A to Z) followed by a number from 1 to 12. The number of the .csv files to change may adapt. But their names are always following the mentioned rules.

I would be very grateful, if somebody could help me with this issue!

Comment: In that directory, are there only these `.csv` files you want to edit, or are there other `.csv` files as well?

Comment: There are only the .csv files that have to be editted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a vector with all filenames that exist in your folder (as this folder contains no other files than those you want to edit) with

```
setwd( "C:/users/Desktop/Raw/" )
files <- Sys.glob( "*.csv" )
```

and then process them one by one with

```
for( i in files )
{
    df <- read.csv( i )
    new_df <- wrap_frame(df, nr = 61, rownames = "", unique_names = FALSE)
    write.csv(new_df, paste( "C:/users/Desktop/Data/", i, sep = "" ), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly fine!!! Just the way I wanted it to work!

Answer (score 2):

Try out:

```
# vector of file names
my.files <- paste0(c(outer(LETTERS, 1:12, FUN = "paste0")),
                   ".csv")
# for loop
for (i in seq_along(my.files)) {
        df <- read.csv(my.files[i], sep= ",") # open
        new_df <- wrap_frame(df, nr = 61, rownames = "", unique_names = FALSE) # mutate
        write.csv(new_df, paste0("C:/users/Desktop/Data/", my.files[i]),
                  row.names = FALSE) # save
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code doesn't work yet that well. Depending on the first number that is written in `LETTERS, 1:12` it only processes the document having a 1 in its Name (e.g. A1, B1, C1, ...). And if there is no A1 at all, the following error message Pops up:

`Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file A1.csv: No such file or directory`

Did I Forget to do something?

Comment: The vector of file names I defined was based on your statement : _The original .csv files are always called the same way with a letter (A to Z) followed by a number from 1 to 12_. This error states that some files were not found in your working directory. You can get the good files names using `list.files(pattern = "*.csv")` or `Sys.glob("*.csv")` as in @vaettchen's post

Comment: Ah ok, perfect! Thanks a lot!